# disable "Like" from posting on a user's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

i would like to prevent the "Like" action from posting to the user's wall.  i've already finagled it so that the "comment" box doesn't show up, and i would simply like a user to be able to "Like" a post on my site without it posting to their wall.  can i do that from my end?

Answer (score 1):

No; you can't have users post a like to your page without it being visible on their Facebook profile (subject to their privacy settings) - that's pretty much the entire point of the Like button